# Make a list print in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know how I can make this code print in one line. I want the full path of the images to be in one line separated by spaces but I tried many things and I can't seem to make it work for some reason. Here's the code:

```
import os
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(minutes=5)

for root, dirs,files in os.walk('C:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Images'):
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        st = os.stat(path)
        ctime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_ctime)
        if ctime > ago:
            print(path.replace('Images\\', 'Images/'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly set the end character when printing:

```
print(path.replace('Images\\', 'Images/'), end=' ')
```